# relative layout and listview in relative which in scrollview android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scrollview

There're an elements of textview, button and imageview..etc on the top of the layout,but the large of part has listview. It's required, when we scroll, top elemnts must scrolling too with listview.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.revolage.vkcommunity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/vk_white"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.egay.borsh.fragments.MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    style="@style/ActionBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

        ......
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.costum.android.widget.PullAndLoadListView
        android:id="@+id/main_post_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_linear_layout" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

but so, nothing is scrolling.

Comment: You shoud not put a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView` as the `ListView` already contains a scroll mecanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this scenario you need to use an expandable ListView. Its a list view thats always expanded. So you can put it inside ScrollView. For your pullAndReflesh custom list view, you should check an expandable and extend your class from that. You can find this class on google.

Why a listView inside scrollview?

Because sometimes you need to use a adapter which cant be used with a LinearLayout for example.